# Why isn't my AlarmManager working?

Tags: android, android-fragments, timer, alarmmanager

I am trying to make an alarm that triggers an event some number of seconds from now, one time, from within a DialogFragment.

Here is the relevant code, I put in onCreate():

```
broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
        Toast.makeText(c, "Rise and Shine!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
getActivity().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(ALARM_MANAGER_TAG) );
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, new Intent(ALARM_MANAGER_TAG), 0 );
alarmManager = (AlarmManager)(getActivity().getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));
```

And then when I press the start button:

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, timestampEnd, pendingIntent);
```

In this case `timestampEnd = System.currentTimeMillis() + 10 * 1000;`, 10 seconds.

And then I have overridden destroy:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

And yet, nothing happens for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP`, which means the `AlarmManager` is going to use [`SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime()) when checking timestamps. Since you're passing something calculated off of `System.currentTimeMillis()`, you are going to have to wait about 47 years before the alarm fires.

Either change your first argument to `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP` or change your timestamp to be calculated off of `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`.

Comment: What's the difference between elapsed realtime and rtc wakeup? Marginal time vs. absolute time?

Comment: You can read the docs, but basically one of them is a timestamp starting at 0 when the device booted, and one of them is a timestamp starting at 0 on 1/1/1970 00:00.

Comment: Hmmm for some reason the timer doesn't seem to be that accurate though, it's not firing in sync with my UI (it's a few seconds late). Is this normal behavior?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing all of your code, but the docs for AlarmManager include this warning: "Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested."

Comment: Hmmm setExact didn't seem to work either, really strange (I'm testing on an emulator, not minimizing or anything, staring right at the UI)

Comment: I don't know :\ ... my best guesses are (1) AlarmManager takes some extra time to wake up even though you're using `setExact()` (maybe "exact" means "within a few seconds") or (2) the method you're using to update your UI is ticking too quickly.

Comment: It seems to be reasonably accurate for >= 4 seconds, but less than that and there's a bit of a delay